# как в css сменить цвет определенной ссылке?

Tags: css, css-animation, link

а точнее `<a id="place_coins">` ибо когда я ввожу в **css**

```
a #place_coins {
color: red;
}
```

Ничего не происходит а вот как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда опи569шнсание изображения]

Comment: Не color, а background-color. И селектор неверный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас вы указываете, что цвет элемент `#place_coins`, который находится в ссылке `a`. Что бы изменить цвет самой ссылки, нужно селектор указывать вместе:

```css
a#place_coins {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a id="place_coins">Текст</a>
```

Comment: Он все-равно свой цвет не меняет

Comment: @Андрей, меняет. Смотрите, я ответ изменил, теперь можно посмотреть. Возможно у вас в `a` есть другие элементы у которых установлен свой цвет?

Comment: да, поэтому я и хочу изменить

Comment: в `а` у меня `a {
  color:#333333;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:none;
}`

Comment: @Андрей, если вы хотите изменять всех внутренних элементов, то добавьте так: `a#place_coins { color: red !important; }` или так `a#place_coins * { color: red !important; }`

Comment: Не помогает, в debug Firefox даже такого стиля нет `a#place_coins`

Comment: @Андрей, тогда может просто по `a { color: red !important; }` ?

Comment: Не :((( в debug `a {
  color:#333333;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:none;
}
body.css (line 64)
a {
}
header.css`

Comment: @Андрей, тогда я не знаю, что у  вас не так

Comment: Ну блин, а че в **header.css** задан стиль но он отображается пустым `a { }` -_- А вот 3 раз я задаю уже в **match.css** тут уже нету `a{ }`

Comment: @Андрей, а у вас какой браузер? Он может просто открывать старый файл

Comment: новый хром  у меня

Comment: @Андрей, тогда может бэкапы делать. Попробуйте по несколько раз обновить страницу или откройте файл со стилями в браузере и обновите его

Comment: Хаха, в этом и была причина :) Благодарю, наверное сайт тяжелый сразу не обновляется

Comment: @Андрей, та, у меня тоже бывает. Иной раз бесит

Comment: @Андрей Не используйте `!important` без веской необходимости. Для того, чтобы сказать браузеру, что вы используете новую версию, используйте `file.css?v=1`, где `file.css` — путь к файлу, `v?=1` — суффикс с номером версии №1. Если обновите файл и добавите `v?=2`, то браузер скачает обновлённый файл..

Answer (score 3):

```css
#place_coins {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="place_coins">anchor</a>
```

Comment: мне без хрюфа надо, это типа кнопка

Comment: без href не валидно =), но можно

Comment: Я обновил как должно выглядеть, прост с хрюфом будет переходить на линк а мне надо чтоб при клике выбиралась команда и отправлялся оффер

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="func_name(); return false;" >anchor</a>

Comment: Да не, я у парня содрал, у него: `<a id="place-coins" class="waves-effect btn deep-orange darken-1">Сделать ставку</a>` вот ссылка на кнопку: https://csgolounge.com/match?m=12945 там только для авторизованных она появляется